# Xpath search for duplicate

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<log>
    <logentry revision="11956">
        <author>avijendran</author>
        <date>2013-05-20T10:25:19.678089Z</date>
        <msg>
            JIRA-1263 - did something
        </msg>
    </logentry>

    <logentry revision="11956">
        <author>avijendran</author>
        <date>2013-05-20T10:25:19.678089Z</date>
        <msg>
            JIRA-1263 - did something 22 again
        </msg>
    </logentry>
</log>
```

I want to ignore any occurrence of the JIRA-1263 after the first one.

The xpath I am trying is (Which works if the duplicates nodes are following. But if you have duplicates else where(deep down), then it is ignored:

```
<xsl:variable name="uniqueList" select="//msg[not(normalize-space(substring-before(., '&#10;')) = normalize-space(substring-before(following::msg, '&#10;')))]" />
```

Comment: Actually, the message text nodes start the same with `<newline><spaces>JIRA-1263 - did something`. I think you need to specify in more detail what you want to match. You will probably need to use XPath's string manipulation routines to extract that then.

Comment: I don't think XPath 1.0's string manipulation capabilities will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Chris, basically I want to match the first bit - JIRA-XXXX (E.g-JIRA-1263)

Comment: Hi Jens, I am happy to upgrade the library to 2.0. (Changed heading)

Comment: Your xpath seem nearly OK. But I think you have to change order of normalize-space substring-before and look than before space. Also if you like to get the first one use preceding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a *key* at the top level of your stylesheet that groups log entries by their first word:

```
<xsl:key name="logentryByCode" match="logentry"
    use="substring-before(normalize-space(msg), ' ')" />
```

Now you need to select all `logentry` elements where either

- the `msg` does *not* start `JIRA-nnnn` (where nnnn is a number) or
- this entry *is* the first one whose `msg` starts with this word (i.e. the first occurrence of `"JIRA-1234 - anything"` for each ticket number)

(note that these two conditions need not be mutually exclusive):

```
<xsl:variable name="uniqueList" select="log/logentry[
    (
     not(
      starts-with(normalize-space(msg), 'JIRA-') and
      boolean(number(substring-before(substring(normalize-space(msg), 6), ' ')))
     )
    )
  or
    (
     generate-id() = generate-id(key('logentryByCode',
           substring-before(normalize-space(msg), ' '))[1])
    )
 ]/msg" />
```

The `boolean(number(...))` part checks whether a string of text can be parsed as a valid non-zero number (the text in this case being the part of the first word of the message that follows `JIRA-`), and the `generate-id` trick is a special case of the technique known as *Muenchian grouping*.

Equally, you could group the `msg` elements instead of the `logentry` elements, using `match="msg"` in the key definition and `normalize-space(.)` instead of `normalize-space(msg)`.

Comment: thanks. With some changes to your solution I made it working.

In the key part I had to change to **"msg"** from **"logentry"**:
`<xsl:key name="logentryByCode" match="msg" use="substring-before(normalize-space(.), ' ')"/>`

I had to simplify the original condition like this to make it work:
`<xsl:variable name="uniqueList" select="log/logentry/msg[generate-id() = generate-id(key('logentryByCode',substring-before(normalize-space(.), ' '))[1])]"/>`

If you could change your answer with these changes, I am happy to accept your answer and up-vote it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: @avijendr I've clarified my answer with an example of how you can get the `msg` elements rather than the `logentry` ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get each `msg` use `//msg[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'JIRA-1263')]` to get output `JIRA-1263 - did something` and `JIRA-1263 - did something 22 again`.

And if you want to get any element with same codition use `//*[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'JIRA-1263')]` which give same result as previous one.

At the end, if you want to get first `msg` with same condition use `//logentry/msg[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'JIRA-1263')][not(preceding::msg)]` to get output `JIRA-1263 - did something`

Comment: Thanks Navin/Ian am using this in a for-each. These solutions doesn seems to work. I am basically trying to avoid duplicates:                                           "JIRA-1263 - did something 22 again" is a duplicate of "JIRA-1263 - did something"

Comment: @avijendr can you edit the question to make it clearer what you _actually_ want?  What output do you expect given the input you have provided?  If there are several different log messages with the same JIRA number do you want to include the first one, the last one, or some other kind of generated "summary" (e.g. "JIRA-1263 - 2 entries")?  This is sounding increasingly like a standard Muenchian grouping problem keyed on the JIRA number.

Comment: Hi Ian,I've updated teh question. Yes you are right, I need to avoid teh duplicates:  I've updated which works for me slightly.

Comment: @avijendr I've deleted my previous answer (which no longer matches the edited question) and added [an alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16697056/592139).

Answer (score 1):

And here another interpretation of what you try to do.
Find any first logentry which start with JIRA-XXXX.
If this it right try this:

```
  log/logentry[
      starts-with(normalize-space(msg), 'JIRA-') and
      not
      (
        substring-before( normalize-space(msg), ' ')= substring-before( normalize-space(preceding::msg), ' ')
      )]
```

This will find any logentry which starts with `JIRA-` but has not preceding one with the same substring before the first space (JIRA-XXXX) in your example.